# Where is the Anaconda Prompt file located?

Tags: anaconda, conda, prompt

I am trying to locate the Anaconda Prompt file. I am currently running Anaconda Navigator 2.4.2. I never updated it before and i did not install any additional software.

I tried:

- Windows Search bar: However, nothing shows up
- C:\Users\xx\anaconda3: I searched every folder, but there is no prompt
- C:\Windows\System32: there is no anaconda folder

Thanks a lot, really appreciate any help

Comment: It's usually a shortcut with a particular set of command flags defined to set up the Anaconda directories in the right places. I don't have a Windows machine handy to check, but you're probably best off reinstalling Anaconda if you haven't installed any additional software.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

This might mean that i would need to recreate that specific file (I guess it's a batch file?)
I am not too convinced that a reinstall would change anything, since it would just reinstall the same again without the anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a shortcut to `cmd.exe` with comamnds set to activate conda. When Anaconda is installed, it usually is under `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3`

It sounds like you have lsot it, so here is a guide how to recreate it:

1. create a shortcut to cmd.exe
2. Right Click->Properties and then change to the `Shortcut` Tab
3. In the target field, you will need to set it to `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" <Path to activate.bat> <Path to Anaconda installation path>`

For example, the target could look like this:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Program Data\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Program Data\Anaconda3
```

Comment: This solved it. 

Thanks a lot, keep it coming 